# NPAPI (npruntime) on linux

Tags: c++, linux, npapi, npruntime

I'm developing a NPAPI npruntime plugin under Linux platform. I just modified a little bit in npruntimeSample from mozilla SDK. I got a successful build and my library was generated but the browser (Firefox and Chromium) doesn't detect the plugin information or Object instantiated.
 I didn't get the reason behind that. Some help if that possible.

Here is my code :
[My sample code on github](https://github.com/AnouarAbdelbari/npruntimle)

Comment: What is the name of your plugin? Where (and how) did you install it?

Comment: It's a shared libraries Eclipse project named "test" and generate a file "libtest.so"

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no npruntime sample in any current Mozilla source base, so you must be looking at some old code.
I recommend trying more recent samples like the one from the [NPAPI SDK](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/unix-basic) or [npsimple](https://github.com/mikma/npsimple) (note that you want to use [this pull request](https://github.com/mikma/npsimple/pull/1), as xulrunner-sdk is dead).

Also, if you're not aware of it, check out [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) for a project that simplifies developing plugins.

Comment: I knew about FireBreath but I want a basic npruntime (Scriptable) sample working on linux and under chromium.

Comment: Try [npsimple](https://github.com/mikma/npsimple) + [this pull request](https://github.com/mikma/npsimple/pull/1)? I'd first be worried about getting something loading though, you can still add scripting from examples to a loading plugin later.